# Mirroring a number in Java, between a specified domain

Tags: java, loops, math

I need to make a mirroring of a a known domain (bounds are algebraic numbers) in Java language.

The domain is between these two numbers, where the 50 is the mirror (50 must be excluded, 50 = 50)! The mirroring need to be in both directions (see examples).

```
0 ________ 50 ________ 100
```

What I want to achieve is this

For example:

```
double x = 20; //x is my input number
double mirrorX = newnumber_mirrored; //mirrorX is the number mirrored in the specified domain, so if the x is 20, the output must be 80.

//other examples:
//input x = 45, output = 55
//input x = 48, output = 52
//input x = 50, output = 50
//input x = 50.1, output = 49.9
//input x = 67.4, output 32.6
```

How can I achieve this in Java? Can be a precision of 1 or maybe 2 decimals, or maybe a fully precision.

Comment: Use the fact that `50 - x = mirrorX - 50`. Use `BigDecimal` if you need full precision.

Comment: Do you study *algebra*?

Comment: Shame on me. I didn't think that may be so easy. Firstly I was confused about the decimal precision and the reverse order. So, I agree with you - I need to get again the algebra course.

Comment: Last out put is wrong

Comment: @Ruchira, yes you're right. Now is correct.

Comment: @ApopeiAndreiIonut you can check my answer too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double x = 20; //x is my input number
double mirrorX = 100 - x;
```

Or, in general, for domain `a` ... `b`:

```
double x = 45;
double a = 30;
double b = 100;
double mirrorX = (a + b) - x; // => 85
```

How to get there:

Our numbers are arranged like this:

```
a             mirror      x      b
```

`mirror` is in the middle between `a` and `b`, so: `mirror = (a + b) / 2`

We want the mirrored `x` to have the same distance to `mirror`, but in the other direction. The distance to `mirror` is `(x - mirror)`, we could express `x` as `mirror + (x - mirror)`. Changing the direction leads to `mirror - (x - mirror)`, the result that we want, which can now be transformed:

```
x_mirrored = mirror - (x - mirror)
x_mirrored = mirror - x + mirror
x_mirrored = 2 * mirror - x
x_mirrored = 2 * ((a + b) / 2) - x
x_mirrored = (a + b) - x
```

Comment: It's not going to get easier.

Comment: Although this might seem simple and obvious code, there are numbers for which this arithmetic won't work. Ie x plus mirrorX won't equal 100.

Comment: Thank you sir, you would have been good teacher. Unless you are already :).